# Does the Young's inequality $x^2+ y^2\geq 2xy$ hold for negatives $x$ or $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, exponential-function

I have noticed in the literature that Young's inequality $x^2+ y^2\geq 2xy$ is mentioned considering non-negative $x$ and $y.$ But considering various cases, I have found that the inequality holds for negative non zero $x$ and $y.$ Does the Young's inequality hold for negatives $x$ or $y$ in general ?

Case 1 : $x=-1, y=1\implies1+1\geq-1$ (Inequality holds).

Case 2 : $x=1, y=-1\implies 1+1\geq-1$ (Inequality holds).

Case 3 : $x=-1, y=-1\implies 1+1 \geq 1$ (Inequality holds)

Comment: No, it's always stated for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$. It is always true that $(x-y)^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: In yourr three cases, the numbers on the right should be $-2,-2,2$ instead of $-1,-1,1$. But yeah, the inequality still holds.

Answer (score 9):

The Young inequality it's the following.

Let $x$, $y$ be non-negative numbers, $p$ and $q$ be positive numbers such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Prove that:
$$\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{y^q}{q}\geq xy.$$
Indeed, for $p=q=2$ we get $x^2+y^2\geq2xy$,

but the last inequality is true for all reals $x$ and $y$ because it's just $(x-y)^2\geq0$.

But in the general case it's wrong.

For example. Try $p=\frac{3}{2}$ and $q=3$.

Hence, we obtain
$$\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{1}{3}y^3\geq xy
,$$
which is obviously wrong for $x=-1$.

Comment: But for the general inequality you stated, it can't hold for negative $x,y$ since those powers are not even necessarily well-defined.

Comment: @wythagoras Yes of course!

Answer (score 8):

The inequality $x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$ holds for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$; indeed, it is equivalent to $(x-y)^2\geq 0$, which always holds when $x-y\in \Bbb R$. Note that changing the sign of $x$ or $y$ only change the RHS, so if the inequality holds for nonnegative numbers it must hold for all reals.

The reason you've seen it stated for nonnegative $x,y$ is probably that a lot of inequalities are only valid for nonnegative numbers, so it is "usual" to add that hypothesis, even though here it is not necessary.

As a side note, I've never seen this inequality being called "Young's inequality" : for me that name applies to the more general inequality
$$\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{y^{q}}{q}\geq xy, $$
where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ (your case is the one where $p=q=2$); this one is in general only true for $x,y\geq 0$, since otherwise $x^p$ and $y^q$ wouldn't be defined.

Comment: I hadn't seen Michael's answer before I edited mine, it's a bit redundant now...